# Joomla 3.4 override com_content/default_articles.php with blog_item

Tags: php, joomla, overriding

i'm working on the category overrides (com_content/category/) right now and trying to display  the items of each category directly under its category

like this:

maincat (com_content/category/default_articles.php)

-cat 1 (com_content/category/default_children)

-- undercat1 1 (com_content/category/blog_item.php)

-- undercat1 2

so i need to insert code from blog_item.php into default_articles or default_children

this

```
<div class="test"> 
  <?php echo $this->item->event->beforeDisplayContent; ?>
   <?php echo $this->item->introtext; ?>  
</div>
```

needs to go into default_articles but i get a property error, also tried to use different variable names - same error. 
Error:

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$event in D:\xampp\htdocs\joomla\templates\protostar\html\com_content\category\default_children.php on line 66

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\joomla\templates\protostar\html\com_content\category\default_children.php on line 66

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$introtext in D:\xampp\htdocs\joomla\templates\protostar\html\com_content\category\default_children.php on line 66

Line 66 from default_children.php:

`<?php echo $this->item->event->beforeDisplayContent; ?> <?php echo $this->item->introtext; ?>`

(this line is originally from com_content/category/blog_item.php, i want it to be in default_children.php)

default_children.php

```
 <?php
 /**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  com_content
  *
  * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters, Inc. All      rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
   */

  defined('_JEXEC') or die;

   JHtml::_('bootstrap.tooltip');

   $lang    = JFactory::getLanguage();
    $class = ' class="first"';
        ?>

   <?php if (count($this->children[$this->category->id]) > 0) : ?>
  <?php foreach ($this->children[$this->category->id] as $id => $child) : ?>
      <?php
    if ($this->params->get('show_empty_categories') ||       $child->getNumItems(true) || count($child->getChildren())) :
        if (!isset($this->children[$this->category->id][$id + 1])) :
            $class = ' class="last"';
          endif;
    ?>

    <div<?php echo $class; ?>>
        <?php $class = ''; ?>
        <?php if ($lang->isRTL()) : ?>
        <h3 class="page-header item-title">
            <?php if ( $this->params->get('show_cat_num_articles', 1)) : ?>
                <span class="badge badge-info tip hasTooltip" title="<?php    echo JHtml::tooltipText('COM_CONTENT_NUM_ITEMS'); ?>">
                    <?php echo $child->getNumItems(true); ?>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($child->id));?>">
            <?php echo $this->escape($child->title); ?></a>

            <?php if (count($child->getChildren()) > 0 && $this->maxLevel > 1) : ?>
                <a href="#category-<?php echo $child->id;?>" data-toggle="collapse" data-toggle="button" class="btn btn-mini pull-right"><span class="icon-plus"></span></a>
            <?php endif;?>
        </h3>
        <?php else : ?>
        <h3 class="page-header item-title"><a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($child->id));?>">
            <?php echo $this->escape($child->title); ?></a>
            <?php if ( $this->params->get('show_cat_num_articles', 1)) : ?>
                <span class="badge badge-info tip hasTooltip" title="<?php echo JHtml::tooltipText('COM_CONTENT_NUM_ITEMS'); ?>">
                    <?php echo $child->getNumItems(true); ?>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (count($child->getChildren()) > 0 && $this->maxLevel > 1) : ?>
                <a href="#category-<?php echo $child->id;?>" data-toggle="collapse" data-toggle="button" class="btn btn-mini pull-right"><span class="icon-plus"></span></a>
            <?php endif;?>
        <?php endif;?>
        </h3>
        <?php if ($this->params->get('show_subcat_desc') == 1) :?>
            <?php if ($child->description) : ?>
                <div class="category-desc">
                    <?php echo JHtml::_('content.prepare', $child->description, '', 'com_content.category'); ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

          <div class="test">   <?php echo var_dump($this->item) ?>   </div>
        <?php echo $this->item->event->beforeDisplayContent; ?> <?php echo $this->item->introtext; ?>


        <?php if (count($child->getChildren()) > 0 && $this->maxLevel > 1) :?>
        <div class="collapse fade" id="category-<?php echo $child->id;?>">
            <?php
            $this->children[$child->id] = $child->getChildren();
            $this->category = $child;
            $this->maxLevel--;
            echo $this->loadTemplate('children');
            $this->category = $child->getParent();
            $this->maxLevel++;
            ?>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

´

I'm not yet that good with PHP - probably some of you could give me a hint towards a solution?

thank you

Comment: Can you please put the exact text of the message and the exact code into your question? It can't be what is there because you are missing the open php tag.

Comment: Try adding `var_dump($this->item)` and see what the property names are.

Comment: "object(stdClass)#290 (1) { ["params"]=> NULL }" comes from var_dump($this->item)

Comment: So that's the problem., it's an array and there is nothing called `introtext`. How is it that the item is referred to in the core layout?  See if it is inside `$this`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do but I think you are confused about that the `default_children` template is doing. It is not displaying articles, it is displaying information on any child categories of the category that is defining the blog. Hence in the code you posted you don't see any reference to `$item` you see references to `$child`. Categories do not have `introtext` they have `description` and thus you see `$child->description`.

The file you want to override is `default_articles`.   If you look in there you will see references to `$article->created_by_alias`  so that tells you probably you want `$article->introtext`.

Comment: com_content/category/default_children are the children of category. com_content/category/blog_item.php are the items in that children category. so i want to display them right into that children category i have. so the user dont have to click on that children category to get to the blog items, but can see the category and unter that directly the blog items. on this blog items he can click to get the full text. basically i want to use code from blog_item in default_children. i hope you understand and can help me :(

Comment: If you want to separate out your items by category then you need to start at the beginning of the layout and organize how the looping through the items is managed. You might want to look at the layout ordering options for category views.